# How can I use this localstorage example to plug into this script?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage, swap

I complied a script that tells multiple divs through this website http://www.martyregan.com/ to swap from the English div to the Japanese div by clicking the "Website Language" buttons.

It works the way I'd like it, though my client would like to know if it's possible for the DIVs to stay on the Japanese DIV when going to another page.

The script currently tells the First Child class (of the two corresponding divs) to show and to hide any other sharing that class.

It also tells the first child class to be the active one, so I'd imagine there IS a way to implement some sort of cache/memory script to work with this.

```
    $(function() {
$('#left-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v, #right-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v, #pb_sidebar .ddsmoothmenu-v, #main-content-inner .content, #main-content-inner .contact, #main-content-inner .right, #main-content-inner .program, #main-content-inner .worksnav, #main-content-inner .worksnav2, #main-content-inner .heading').hide();
$('#left-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v:first, #right-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v:first, #pb_sidebar .ddsmoothmenu-v:first, #main-content-inner .content:first, #main-content-inner .contact:first, #main-content-inner .right:first, #main-content-inner .program:first, #main-content-inner .worksnav:first, #main-content-inner .worksnav2:first, #main-content-inner .heading:first').show();
$('#language a:first').addClass('active');

$('#language a').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('active') == true) {
    return false;
}
else {
    $('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('#left-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v, #right-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v, #pb_sidebar .ddsmoothmenu-v, #main-content-inner .content, #main-content-inner .contact, #main-content-inner .right, #main-content-inner .program, #main-content-inner .worksnav, #main-content-inner .worksnav2, #main-content-inner .heading').fadeOut();
    var contentToLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    $(contentToLoad).fadeIn();

    return false;
}
});
});
```

Here is the example I was given:

```
$('a.en').click(function(){
localStorage.setItem('language', 'en');
});

$('a.fr').click(function(){
localStorage.setItem('language', 'fr');
});

// to get the language value use getItem
localStorage.getItem('language');
```

Comment: very bad way to create multi language website; only one language will be indexed by search engine as a result you can expect to get about 0 visitor from japan (+ japanese hardly speak any english so even if they end up on that english page chances are real small they figure out they can have it in japanese). sure you put a language option but your first goal is that users never ever need to use that language option - so forgive me to not even finish reading the question

Comment: oh believe me my friend. I am COMPLETELY aware. this client of mine refused 1. to use the custom built content management system from my old web firm (who still let's me use it and bring them hosting) because he was too cheap and found cheaper hosting... Ever hear of Concrete5? It's AWFUL. 2. refused to use subdomains for me to split up the language...why? I really do not know. him and I discussed on the phone earlier about possibly still doing...and neither of us remember why he didn't want to split the site up. the man is a moron and owes me a lot of money. this is the LAST thing I am doing.

Comment: @mikakun Any idea how can I just plug that example into this script? You have no idea how many scripts I'm running on this site to make it do this shit it's doing. It's awful and I just want to wipe my hands clean of this project. He may want to do the subdomains if I can't figure this out, but I honestly don't want to do any more work for this guy, even if he's paying more. He's the worst.

Comment: lol editors are all the worst... cookie shall be enough to save a string over the session though. you hide everything by default then you fade in elements depending on cookie value https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @mikakun I really don't know jack about programming. I know how to alter scripts to extent, but this one I'm lost on. I really don't know what to do next and I was trying to make tonight the deadline. Is there any way you can help me further?

Comment: so you didn't want to pay a coder to do that job & now you ask for free advice... either you learn either you contract; it sounds like you want the butter and the money of the butter

Comment: @mikakun LOLOL I am so anxious that I don't even want to wait until tomorrow for the programmer over at my old web firm (that i offered money to) to look at the script in the email I sent him a few hours ago. that's how much I want to get paid by this guy. I am completely willing to pay anyone for their time to do this. what is wrong with asking for free advice? isn't that what this site is for...? lawl. I'm not a programmer, so I don't know how hard this is. do you want to beat the programmer that I reached out to, to the punch? be my guest or be a tool. learn? i wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: imo SOF is a website for programmers, whether beginners whether experts to share experience & learn from each other. you'd be better off with freelancer.com & sorted out in no time for a very small fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question can be solved quickly,
so instead of telling you once again that this can be solved by any freelancer
i hope i just did it ;)

this is untested, since it would be pretty too much effort to create the testenvironment,

but it *should* work, IF you add an html id tag to the links of the language chooser,

```
<div id="language">
    <a id="en" href="#mainnaven, #contenten, #contacten, #works_righten, #works_programen,  #worksnaven,  #worksnav2en, #works_headen" class="">
        <img src="http://www.martyregan.com/files/1413/5826/9756/en.png">
    </a>
    <a id="jp" href="#mainnavjp, #contentjp, #contactjp, #works_rightjp, #works_programjp, #worksnavjp, #worksnav2jp, #works_headjp" class="active">
        <img src="http://www.martyregan.com/files/5213/5826/9759/jp.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

notice the id="en" and the id='jp' that i added to the divs.

if thats not possible we will have to add a few more lines.

the script then would be:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var language = localStorage.getItem('language');

  if(!language) {
    language = "en";
  }

  $('#left-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v').fadeOut(function(){

    var link =  $('#'+language);
    var contentToLoad = link.attr('href');

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    link.addClass('active');

    $(contentToLoad).fadeIn();
  });


  $('#left-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v').show();
  $('#language a:first').addClass('active');

  $('#language a').live('click',function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var language = 'jp';
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('mainnaven') > 0 ) {
          language = 'en'
        }

        localStorage.setItem('language', language);

        $('#left-sidebar-inner .ddsmoothmenu-v').fadeOut();
        var contentToLoad = $(this).attr('href');

        $(contentToLoad).fadeIn();

        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

have fun

jascha

Comment: Wow...you rule man. Though, I'm getting a syntax error here:

if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('mainnaven'){

Comment: darn it, thats my most common typo... forgot a ) :)

i edited the script above

Comment: Hmm...I have a test environment...The menu seems to disappear :/ Check it out: http://dev523.webdugout.com/Files/112648/test.zip I really appreciate the help man, seriously.

Comment: you are missing the id="en" and id="jp" tags i wrote about above :)

<a **id="en"** href="#mainnaven" class=""><img /></a>. you can just copy/paste that few lines of html in my post above over yours, its exactly the same, i just added the ids

Comment: Wait...no way. I know I had them in at first. But you're right when I made that zip I must've removed them. The menu stays, but the swap isn't working now. =/

Comment: I feel kinda dumb, because I know I made sure that I had them in...I don't know, but now the menu itself isn't swapping from the buttons.

Comment: hi again :) its working for me now, i updated the script above. it only has one cosmetic fail: it shows the english language shortly before showing the real language on every pageload. this could be circumvented but would be quite a bit of work. it also is not beautiful javascript at all. i wouldnt advise to use this ever again ;)

Comment: So close! It's loading both menus at first!

Comment: I got it I got it! I know why, I removed :first from the code. You are the man! And I know, this script SUCKS! I will never again use it. I really appreciate all the help! Thanks so much man!

Comment: your welcome :) enjoy your freedom of this project, wrap it up, deploy it and forget :)

Comment: By the way, I will pay for any circumvention of the script to make it less hiccup-y. My client already whines about how it bounces, but that's because each div is relative to each other, but REALLY needs to be positioned absolute so that things don't bounce, but I can't do that because then the containers these swapping divs are in don't know the correct heights. Could not think of any workarounds that actually worked, hah. Oh, but check it out on the site, works perfect, thanks! http://www.martyregan.com/

Comment: Crap, only thing I'm noticing is that when the site isn't cached yet, like if I open it on Opera or Chrome for the first time, the page loads both the EN and JP containers. Hm...

Comment: now it will always switch at first load,
then load english as the default or japanese if it has been chosen before. for the containers: if you give them position:absolute;display:block;width:600px;height:600px; the children should get the dimensions correctly, but answering that problem is far beyond the area of this question ;)